# Problem with action mapping

Tags: input, unreal-4, mouse, blueprints

Summarizing my problem well, I need a single button (right mouse button) to do two things.

In my project (TopDown) I defined that instead of the *left mouse button*, the character moves with the *right mouse button*.

I happen to like that when I click the right mouse button on a particular actor, a simple event is called (print hello).

**I tried doing this with the Event On Clicked, but it only works with the left mouse button:**

[image]

[image]

**With the help of these links:**

https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/blog/input-action-and-axis-mappings-in-ue4

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/134349/right-click-on-an-actor.html

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/17729/how-to-create-a-right-mouse-click-event-with-bluep.html

I figured out how to do an action/event call with the right mouse button, but even then I did not succeed.

**Soon I discovered that the reason was that there was already an action that was executed with the right mouse button (walk/set destination):**

[image]

I would like my character to continue to move with the right click of the mouse, but how do I also call an event when I click the right mouse button?

---

**EDIT 1**

**If the mapping is done with two different keys, it works perfectly:**

[image]

**In this case the character jumps and walks (instead of jumping it could be anything else):**

[image]

**I want this to happen by right-clicking (walking and jumping):**

[image]

This action I want to perform is when clicking on the mesh of any actor, but I can only do this with the left button.

Comment: If UE4 cant direct the same mapping to 2 actions you should do it manually - make one mapping e.g OnRMB - and then call both of your actions manually from the OnRMB

Comment: @ColdSteel could you send me the link for some example of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem I would have to know how to modify the **Input Action Set Destination**, or simply reproduce what the **Input Action Set Destination** does.

**With the help of this question (which I was able to answer, it was a simple mistake) I was able to figure out how to make the character walk based on the mouse click:**

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/260158/making-a-top-down-mouse-following-character.html?childToView=910918#answer-910918

**Just create an Action Mapping:**

[image]

**Using the code below you can get the character to go to the mouse click (ignore the pink circles, I re-used the image):**

[image]

**Based on the previous code, it was only me that added a condition based on the actor that was clicked:**

[image]

*In the future this condition will be something involving the floor of the level, but for the answer I used the tower and inverted logic.*

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the RMB to trigger the event, then use the "Button Pressed" pin from the OnClicked method to check if it's a right-click or not before continuing.

You can also use [GetEffectingButton](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Utilities/PointerEvent/GetEffectingButton/index.html) and do a check to see if its RMB as illustrated [here](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/17729/how-to-create-a-right-mouse-click-event-with-bluep.html).

EDIT:

So you want two different possible actions to occur with the exact same input?

Then you won't be able to have two different action mappings, because as far as Unreal is concerned, its the same input, unless you have a modifier like Alt, Shift, etc. You'll have to do the check on your end.

I would suggest tagging the possible static meshes that can be clicked and then checking the tag of the touched object. For example, tag the terrain they can walk on with 'terrain' and the characters/items they can access a context menu with 'context'. Then call custom functions depending on which tag you find when they click.

(From a design standpoint, I do not recommend having movement and context menu on same input. Look at League & DOTA, the most popular top-down games. Movement is RMB, inspect & interact is LMB. Otherwise you can have accidental movement when a player is just trying to look.)

Comment: In Button Pressed pin nothing appears on the right mouse button.

Comment: I did not find the function (OnMouseButtonDown), even looking for Override Functions. This is because I want to apply the click to an actor, not to a widget.

Comment: If this is not a widget I discourage using the OnClicked in graph - it will not allow for easy key binding later on.